# php downloaded files in zip are empty

Tags: php, file, zip

currently I am trying to put files in a zip and download them. I use the following code:

```
 # create new zip opbject
$zip = new ZipArchive();

# create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

# loop through each file
foreach($files as $file){

    # download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

    #add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);

}

# close zip
$zip->close();

# send the file to the browser as a download
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Resumes.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
```

The files are added to the array the following way:

```
$weborder = $_POST['weborder'];
$printlocation = $_POST['print'];

$dir = "z:\Backup\\$printlocation\\$weborder.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive; 
$files = array();

if ($zip->open($dir)) 
{
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) 
    {
        if ($zip->getNameIndex($i) != "order-info.txt" && $zip->getNameIndex($i) != "workrequest.xml" && $zip->getNameIndex($i) != "workrequest.pdf") 
        {
            $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);

            $files[$i] = $dir . "\\" . $filename;
        }
    }
}
```

This downloads the zip and the files that are in the zip. The only problem I am having is that the files are empty.

Comment: files are added to zip?

Comment: Yes, they are. I added the method I use to add the files to the zip.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working make sure that your files are existed or not.

```
$array = array("sites/README.txt","sites/chessboard.jpg"); //files to Add/Create in zip file

$zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
{ 
 // Opening zip file to load files
$error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{ 
    if(file_exists($value)){
        $zip->addFile($value); // Adding files into zip
    }else{echo $value ."&nbsp;&nbsp;file not exist<br/>";}
}
$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name))
{
    echo "yes";die;
// push to download the zip
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
readfile($zip_name);
// remove zip file is exists in temp path
unlink($zip_name);
}else{echo "zip not created";die; }
```

For **Download** Existing file

```
 $zip_name = "YOUR_ZIP_FILE PATH";
    if(file_exists($zip_name))
    {
    // push to download the zip
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    readfile($zip_name);
    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
    //unlink($zip_name);
    }else{
        echo "zip not created";exit; 
    }
```

Comment: The files that I am trying to download are already in a zip file. When I try your code it says that the file didnt exist. Is it possible to download a file in a zip that is already located in a zip?

Comment: try below code to download your zip file "For Download Existing file" use this code

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);
```

try

```
$zip->addFile($basename($file));
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the following errors: "No such file or directory" and "Function name must be a string "

Comment: I am giving the correct file path. The files are being downloaded only there size is 0kb.

Comment: replace your header like this -> header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$tmp_file);
header('Content-Length:'.filesize($tmp_file)); header('Content-Type: application/zip');

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help either.